# for loop and forEach loop not working in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a to-Do App and i'm having a hard time getting the POST request working. i have tried using a for loop and a for Each Loop.  does not work.

```
<% todos.forEach(item => { %>
    <li><%= items.item %></li>
<% });%>
```

and also this

```
<% for(let i=0; i < todos.length; i++) { %>
    <li><%= todos[i].item %></li> 
<% } %>
```

My app.js:

```js
const express= require('express');
const todoController = require ('./controllers/todoController');

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('./public'));
todoController(app);

app.listen(3000);
```

My controller:

```js
let data = [
    { item: 'wake up and pray' },
    { item: 'go to the gym' }, 
    { item: 'fire my laptop and...CODE!!' }
];

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/todo' ,function(req, res) {
        res.render('todo', {todos:data});
    });

    app.post('/todo',function(req, res) {
        data.push(req.body);
        res.render('todo', {todos:data});
    });

    app.delete('/todo' ,function(req, res) {});
};
```

This is the error messages:

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\HP LAPTOP\Desktop\toDoApp\views\todo.ejs:20
   18|         <ul>
   19|                 <% todos.forEach(item => { %>
>> 20|                     <li><%= items.item %></li>
   21|                     <% });%> 
   22|      </ul>
   23| </body>
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you give us the error from the log if there is one?

Comment: edited the post and added the error message

Comment: Use alias item. <li><%= item %></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have looped with "todos.forEach(**item** => {});" but used "**items**.item.".

**EDITED**
The Right code is

```html
<% todos.forEach(function (item) { %>
   <li><%= item.item %></li>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: hi! i'm still getting the same error message. the error points to the <li>

Comment: Check the Edited Code, I think the arrow function might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<% todos.forEach(item => { %>
    <li><%= items.item %></li>
<% });%>
```

Your JS code is basically `todos.forEach(item => some_formatting(item))`.

Inside the lambda, you have access to `item`, not to `items.item`.

Comment: hi! the error says item is undefined and going through my app.js, i have it defined there. any reason why this might be occuring?

Comment: (1) You define `item` as a parameter of the lambda inside `.forEach`. (2) Apparently ejs does not work with lambdas; their docs suggest using a `function`.